# I need a div besides a div with one under

Tags: css, html

Hello i need help to create a extra div besides my existing content.
http://jsfiddle.net/2zWFE/

```
<div></div>
```

It should be to the right of it 200px wide, height doesn't matter. When i try to do it by myself it brakes the placement of my content.

I know that it' pretty messy but i'm trying to learn so don't comment that :).

I would appreciate if someone could help me with it!

Comment: Do you want it beside the header or the part below the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2zWFE/6/

I basically created a div element to contain the main content and another separate div and gave them both the property `display: inline-block`.  Then, I made another div to contain them both and center them with `text-align: center` in order to keep the formatting.  Also, I fixed a `<h6>` tag that never had the ending `>` and got rid of some unnecessary `</div>`s.  I also added `vertical-align: top` to keep the new div positioned at the same top height as the other.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/75yPeWA.png This how i want it to look like. And when i tried yours the inlined text was written on the news side.

Comment: Ok that should be easy - 1 second

Comment: My answer has been improved.

Comment: Perfect.  If you were satisfied, you should probably mark the answer as accepted so that future visitors looking for a solution to a similar problem may find the answer fast and easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this using floats.

Essentially you need to place the left side content in a container div, float it left, then float #logo left as well. Since the container comes first, it will be the left-most div and then, space permitting, #logo will line up along side the div along the right side of the container.

All I did (besides cleaning up some syntax issues) was move your logo div to the bottom, then wrap everything but that with the container like...

```
<div class="container">

existing non-#logo markup

</div> 

<div id="logo" align="center"><img src="images/header.png" width="584" height="200" /></div>
```

The CSS is just one property applied to #logo and .container

```
.container, #logo {
    float:left;
}
```

If you'd like for the #logo to stick to the right side, you can apply a float of right to the #logo div.

You can take a look at my forked fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/BlakePetersen/vE8T6/5/

**UPDATE**
New fiddle has been updated to include within and outside of main container box. Inside example of a right float, outside, a left float.

Comment: The problem is that the image was moved to the bottom which is not the intended formatting.

Comment: Forgot to save my fiddle... refreshed... FML

Comment: It's updated now, also tossed in the width adjustment, to ensure consistent aspect ratio, the image's height attribute needs to be nixed otherwise it will force it to use that height unless the height is also defined in CSS, which it's not.

Comment: Just saw the bit about placing the image within the content. I added a second reference in my fiddle to the right of the infocontainer box. Two examples, one floating left of all of the content, one floating right of the content in the info box.

http://jsfiddle.net/BlakePetersen/vE8T6/5/

Comment: Cheers guys, i will look more into it tomorrow going to sleep now.